# Is it possible in Stryker.NET to exclude only internal methods/constructors

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, stryker

According to the part [Ignore-Methods](https://stryker-mutator.io/docs/stryker-net/configuration/#ignore-methods-string) of the documentation of **Stryker.NET** it is possible to define methods and/or constructors to be skipped in the mutation like in the following example:

```
"stryker-config": {
    "ignore-methods": [
        "*Log", // Ignores all methods ending with Log
        "Console.Write*", // Ignores all methods starting with Write in the class Console
        "*Exception.ctor" // Ignores all exception constructors
    ]
}
```

Is it possible only to exclude **internal** constructors?

As a workaround I use the [Stryker comments](https://stryker-mutator.io/docs/stryker-net/ignore-mutations/#stryker-comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.

Just to make things clear, the `ignore-method` [option](https://stryker-mutator.io/docs/stryker-net/configuration/#ignore-methods-string) doesn't ignore the code of the methods in question but the calls to them, or rather mutations in the calls to them.

For example, in the following code, if you put `"ignore-methods": [ "Method2" ]` in your config, your mutants will play out like this:

```cs
public static class Library
{
    public static bool Method1()
    {
        return Method2(true); // boolean mutation ignored
    }

    public static bool Method2(bool p)
    {
        return true; // boolean mutation not ignored
    }
}
```

On a technical side of things, Stryker works with Roslyn APIs and looks at the `ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax`, not at the `ConstructorDeclarationSyntax` (where it could theoretically distinguish constructors by the declared accessibility).

So I guess it's not easy to propagate this kind of requirement to the Stryker core. Though - doable, hence you can create a feature request [here](https://github.com/stryker-mutator/stryker-net/issues/new?assignees=&labels=%F0%9F%9A%80+Feature+request&projects=&template=feature_request.md&title=). IMHO this is quite a niche ask.